# Como criar um driver para fazer meu próprio mouse usb com PIC?

Tags: c++, pic, driver

Olá,

Eu estou tentando desenvolver um mouse usando um pic e ao invés de usar um sensor óptico geralmente usado em mouses eu queria controlar usando acelerômetros.

Como eu faço para criar um driver pro Windows?
É possível eu comunicar um PIC com um driver que eu criei e comandar um mouse?

Comment: Mais fácil seria fazer o PIC mandar os comandos de um mouse normal. O problema é que o protocolo HID não é tão simples assim a ponto de você fazer um stack completo USB só com PIC (com Arduino é muito mais fácil). Mas tem chips que fazem parte do trabalho "pesado". Quanto à pergunta, está um bocado ampla no meu ver. Seria legal uma lida no [Tour], [Ask] e [Escopo do site](/help/on-topic) e depois dar uma editada na pergunta para torná-la mais objetiva, para aproveitar melhor o site.

Comment: Olá, eu sabia que era genérica a pergunta, fiz ela para que fosse possível que fizessem sugestões de como eu poderia fazer de outras maneiras. O mouse que eu pretendo fazer seria utilizando acelerômetros para capturar a movimentação. Nesse meio tempo desde a pergunta ser feita eu li li li li e vi que é realmente extremamente complicado eaí resolvi outra alternativa. Desmontei um mouse USB e utilizando o mouse scroll consegui controlar o mouse com o autohotkey enviando até 8 bits, porém o mouse tem um debouncing time que faz a movimentação ficar extremamente lenta então desencanei.

Comment: Se você pegar os 2 contatos da wheel e usar o PIC para mandar uma sequência de 01 11 10 00, consegue a velocidade que quiser. O segredo é manter a sequência (01 11 10 00 ou 01 00 10 11 no outro sentido)

Answer (score 1):

Desenvolvimento de drivers é uma área extremamente especializada.

Assim casualmente é impossível criar um driver, você vai precisar estudar bastante o assunto em livros especializados, e experimentar bastante.

A Microsoft fornece muitos exemplos de drivers para o Windows.

Nesta url a Microsoft disponibiliza exemplos de drivers: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples.

O SDK para desenvolvimento de drivers está aqui:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557573(v=vs.85).aspx.

Se você ainda não tem experiência com drivers vai precisar estudar bastante **mesmo**. (Obs. não tenho experiência nessa área).